# Superimpose another graph on subset of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to analyze and visualize data with datetime as the x axis. How can I superimpose another graph(E.g. linear regression) on only a subset of the data?

For example, I'm trying to fit an exponential model from 3/23 to 4/17. The entire data set is from 3/4 to 5/5.

This is the entire data set:
[image: Entire Data set]

This is the exponential model I am trying to fit. The "0" on the x-axis corresponds to 3/23.
[image: Subset]

Here is a minimal working example of the code I am working with:
(1) This is the code used to produce entire graph.

```
def genplot(filename):
    """
    Generates plots
    Args:
        filename: name of csv file as str
    Returns:
        plot
    """
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates = ["DATE"],
                       index_col = ["DATE"])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data.index.values, data["NUMBER"], color = "blue")
    ax.set(xlabel = "date")
    plt.show()
```

I am using Python 3.7
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we have something to work with?

Comment: I recommend you to pass us an example to reproduce it along with its experienced output so we can help you more efficiently